# explorer crashing on CreateProcess hook

Tags: delphi, hook

I'm injecting a DLL inside explorer.exe to hook CreateProcess, this way I can intercept when user open some executables (I choose this hook method because I'm trying to learn more about hooks, I know could be done using WMI, or other ways).
The library I'm using to hook is:
[DDetours](https://code.google.com/p/delphi-detours-library/)

The hook is working, and every app I execute popup the messagebox I set in the HookProc, but right after the messagebox, explorer.exe crashes.
The code to inject DLL is working fine, and if I just inject an empty dll or a dll with just a messagebox everything works properly. So I believe the problem is somewhere in the hook setup. Here is the DLL code:

```
library DLL;

uses
  Windows, DDetours;

{$R *.res}

var
  CreateProcessHook: function(var lpApplicationName:String;
            lpCommandLine:String;
            lpProcessAttributes:IntPtr;
            lpThreadAttributes:IntPtr;
            bInheritHandles:Boolean;
            dwCreationFlags:Int32;
            lpEnvironment:IntPtr;
            lpCurrentDirectory:IntPtr;
            lpStartupInfo:STARTUPINFO;
            lpProcessInformation:PROCESS_INFORMATION): Boolean; stdcall = nil;

function InterceptCreateProcess(lpApplicationName:String;
            lpCommandLine:String;
            lpProcessAttributes:IntPtr;
            lpThreadAttributes:IntPtr;
            bInheritHandles:Boolean;
            dwCreationFlags:Int32;
            lpEnvironment:IntPtr;
            lpCurrentDirectory:IntPtr;
            lpStartupInfo:STARTUPINFO;
            lpProcessInformation:PROCESS_INFORMATION): Boolean; stdcall;
  begin
    MessageBoxA(0, 'Process created :)', 'Hooked', 0);
  end;

procedure DLLMain(dwReason: DWORD);
begin
  case dwReason of
  DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
  begin
    MessageBoxA(0,'Injected', 'Injected', MB_OK);
    @CreateProcessHook:= InterceptCreate(@CreateProcess, @InterceptCreateProcess);
  end;
  end;
end;

begin
 DLLProc := @DLLMain;
 DLLMain(DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH);
end.
```

As you can see, the InterceptCreateProcess just shows a message box, and this is working when I open some executable, but like said above, explorer crashes. I think that's something with the declaration of the CreateProcess function variables. Any tips?
**everything is 64bits**

Comment: Do you have experience with C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your hook functions do not match the proper signature of `CreateProcess()`.  Try this instead:

```
library DLL;

uses
  Windows, DDetours;

{$R *.res}

var
  CreateProcessHook: function(lpApplicationName: PChar;
            lpCommandLine: PChar;
            lpProcessAttributes, lpThreadAttributes: PSecurityAttributes;
            bInheritHandles: BOOL;
            dwCreationFlags: DWORD;
            lpEnvironment: Pointer;
            lpCurrentDirectory: PChar;
            const lpStartupInfo: STARTUPINFO;
            var lpProcessInformation: PROCESS_INFORMATION): BOOL; stdcall = nil;

function InterceptCreateProcess(lpApplicationName: PChar;
            lpCommandLine: PChar;
            lpProcessAttributes, lpThreadAttributes: PSecurityAttributes;
            bInheritHandles: BOOL;
            dwCreationFlags: DWORD;
            lpEnvironment: Pointer;
            lpCurrentDirectory: PChar;
            const lpStartupInfo: STARTUPINFO;
            var lpProcessInformation: PROCESS_INFORMATION): BOOL; stdcall;
begin
  Result := CreateProcessHook(lpApplicationName, lpCommandLine, lpProcessAttributes, lpThreadAttributes, bInheritHandles, dwCreationFlags, lpEnvironment, lpCurrentDirectory, lpStartupInfo, lpProcessInformation);    
  MessageBox(0, 'CreateProcess', 'Hooked', 0);
end;

procedure DLLMain(dwReason: DWORD);
begin
  case dwReason of
    DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    begin
      @CreateProcessHook := InterceptCreate(@CreateProcess, @InterceptCreateProcess);
      MessageBox(0, 'Injected', 'Injected', MB_OK);
    end;
    DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
    begin
      InterceptRemove(@CreateProcessHook);
    end;
  end;
end;

begin
 DLLProc := @DLLMain;
 DLLMain(DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH);
end.
```

Comment: Yes, that worked. Strange thing is that when I tried to use the exactly same signature from msdn (as I put in the main question), still crashing.

Comment: You weren't using the same signature as in msdn

Comment: Right now I put the `Result := CreateProcessHook(lpApplicationName...` trying to open the process previously requested by me, but I got a Windows Error, saying something like: The system cannot find the file specified... with the correct path for the file I openned. Any idea on how to open the file?

Comment: Did you verify the path being received by your detour (not the path you pass to the intercepted `CreateProcess()`) is correct before passing it to the trampoline?

Comment: Yes, because the path appear on the error box. And it's correctly. Maybe is something about Unicode and Ansi... But I tried to change for something like: `Result := CreateProcessHook(PAnsiChar(lpApplicationName)` but doesn't worked.

Comment: Still not working. Did few tests with MessageBox(lpApplicationName) and MessageBox(lpCommandLine), to see what parameters are being passed, everything is correct. Can't understand why I get this error. Is something like: The Windows could not find the file C:\windows\system32\notepad.exe ..... (when openning notepad).

Comment: To avoid any possible Ansi/Unicode issues, you should consider hooking `CreateProcessA()` and `CreateProcessW()` separately. But I don't think this is going to be an Ansi/Unicode issue. Are you SURE everything is compiled for 64bit only? The `system32` folder is subject to UAC/WOW64 redirection.

Comment: @Remy turns out that in a now deleted question asker was still using the wrong signatures for CreateProcess.

Answer (score 3):

Your signature for your `CreateProcess` detour is completely wrong. That function, a Win32 function, does not operate on Delphi strings. And the final two parameters are pointers to structs.

The first step is to fix these signatures. Use the signature from the `Windows` unit in the RTL.

It looks something like this:

```
function CreateProcessW(
  lpApplicationName: PWideChar;
  lpCommandLine: PWideChar;
  lpProcessAttributes: PSecurityAttributes;
  lpThreadAttributes: PSecurityAttributes;
  bInheritHandles: BOOL;
  dwCreationFlags: DWORD;
  lpEnvironment: Pointer;
  lpCurrentDirectory: PWideChar;
  const lpStartupInfo: STARTUPINFO;
  var lpProcessInformation: PROCESS_INFORMATION
): BOOL; stdcall;
```

Comment: Yes I tried to. But still crashing. Wait, I'll try again and paste here the signature.

Comment: Not quite.  See my answer.

Comment: No. You just need to do what I said in my answer. Use the exact same definition as in Windows unit. I rolled back your edit because it invalidated my answer.

Comment: OK. No problem. I'll check the Windows unit. Thank's for help guys.

Comment: Well, like I said I'm just learning more about hook. I'm the kind of person that not quite good with programming (my maths logic is really bad since school days hehe). So I accepted your advice to not mess with windows critical processes. And I got the same point using explorer.exe, so that all good.

Comment: So do you need more help there? Or did I not answer the question. I actually wondered whether you did not yet know how to accept, you being new, and was gently leading you towards that knowledge. But it seems you do know how to accept.

Comment: I can accept, but that answer was just vague about my question. I just thought could be "wrong" to accept an answer that is not really answering the question. If I could accept your comment "Almost anything other than a high integrity critical system process..." would be good. Anyway I'll accept the answer.

Comment: @user I don't agree that it didn't answer the Q. You stated that you had a 32 bit injector with a 64 bit target. And that always fails. I don't see any reason to look beyond that. The comment about csrss being a bad target was more general advice.

Comment: Comments related to another question belong in that question, not this one.